# How to set up multiple websites / virtual hosts on MAMP?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, mamp

How do you configure [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) to manage/host multiple websites at one time for development?

Comment: I don't have the reputation to comment, but I just want to point out that according to this you want to avoid editing the conf files with TextEdit: [Virtual hosts with MAMP](http://sillybean.net/web-design/virtual-hosts-with-mamp/)

Comment: I've had no problems editing it with TextEdit

Comment: Re: textedit- Depends on what’s in the user directory. Some things don’t do well with rtf; just set textedit to ‘plain text’.

Comment: you have to turn off the web sharing in system preferences

Comment: Can someone please help me out here ? I am trying to achieve the same thing in MAMP http://stackoverflow.com/q/40405663/4480164

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### Change your default listening port

Go to `MAMP > Preferences > Ports` and set `Apache Port` to be `80`. Press okay.

### Set up your local hosts file

Edit your hosts file so that you have some domains that will resolve to your local web server.

From Terminal, type `sudo pico /etc/hosts` and type your password. At the bottom, append the following two lines.

```
127.0.0.1    local.example.com
127.0.0.1    local.example.net
```

Save the file and exit (Ctrl+O, enter, Ctrl+X).

### Add Virtual Hosts to your Apache configuration

Open up `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf` in a text editor, scroll down, and add the following lines to the file.

```
NameVirtualHost * 

<VirtualHost *> 
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs" 
ServerName localhost 
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *> 
DocumentRoot "/Users/YOURNAME/sites/example-a" 
ServerName local.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *> 
DocumentRoot "/Users/YOURNAME/sites/example-b" 
ServerName local.example.net
</VirtualHost>
```

### Restart Apache

Stop Servers and then Start Servers on MAMP. Now you should be able to visit:
http://local.example.com/ and http://local.example.net/

Comment: I registered in serverfault just to upvote your answer! :D

Comment: Me too. This is amazing, because you don't have to buy MAMP Pro (which is kind of expensive) for managing multiple sites locally just by editing two config files.

Comment: For access forbidden error, go here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110179/adding-virtualhost-fails-access-forbidden-error-403-xampp-windows-7

Comment: There is a specific file for virtual host configs located here: `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Comment: @BryanDowning It's worth mentioning that in order for apache to use this file you have to uncomment the following line from within httpd.conf file: 
`Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Comment: Can someone please help me out here ? I am trying to achieve the same thing in MAMP http://stackoverflow.com/q/40405663/4480164

Comment: After update my Apache Port from `8888` to be `80`, I can't start my Apache Server on my **MAMP**. Does anyone else experience this ?